# onAreaTouch is still being called after successfully detaching sprite

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, sprite, andengine

This is my code to add sprites on Scene.

```
    for (int i = 3; i <= cage.getDirtMeter(); i++) {
        Sprite dirtSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, Main.dirtTextureRegion,
                mainActivity.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                removeDirt(this);
                return true;
            }
        };
        float x = Utility.getRandomXWithinCamera(dirtSprite);
        float y = Utility.getRandomYWithinCamera(dirtSprite);

        dirtSprite.setPosition(x, y);
        this.registerTouchArea(dirtSprite);
        attachChild(dirtSprite);
    }
```

and here is my removeDirt method

```
public void removeDirt(final Sprite sprite) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (CoolDown.getSharedInstance().checkValidity()) {
            if (isCleanSelected) {
                Log.d("detach", "Calling remove dirt");
                cage.removeDirt();
                mainActivity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        /* Now it is save to remove the entity! */
                        if (MainMenuScene.this.detachChild(sprite)) {
                            Log.d("detach", "detached Successfuly!");
                        }
                    }
                });
                updateMetersUI();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After removeDirt is called sprite isn't visible on screen but sprites onAreaTouch is still being called even sprites is being deAttached successfully. Any idea how to completely remove sprite from scene. thanks. And I have also tried

```
 sprite.setVisible(false);
 sprite.clearEntityModifiers();
 sprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
 sprite.clearUpdateHandlers();
 sprite.reset();
 sprite.detachSelf();
```

But after that onAreaTouch is still being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Unregister Touch Areas of your Sprite from the scene.
eg

```
yourScene.unregisterTouchArea(yourSprite);
```